# Rank of commuting linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ and $T$ be two commuting linear transformation in $L(U)$. Show that $r(S+T)\leq r(S)+r(T)-r(ST)$.

It's obvious that $r(S+T)\leq r(S)+r(T)$.But I don't know which property of commutation makes the inequality more strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for linear subspaces $V,W$ of $U$, we have
$$\dim(V)+\dim(W)=\dim(V+W)+\dim(V\cap W).$$
Apply this to $V=\text{Im}(S)$ and $W=\text{Im}(T)$, where $\text{Im}$ denotes image, to get
$$\dim(\text{Im}(S)) +\dim (\text{Im}(T)) = \dim(\text{Im}(S)+\text{Im}(T))+\dim(\text{Im}(S)\cap \text{Im}(T))$$

Now $\text{Im}(S+T)\subset \text{Im}(S)+\text{Im}(T)$, hence $\dim(\text{Im}(S)+\text{Im}(T))\geq \dim(\text{Im}(S+T))$.

And $\text{Im}(ST)=\text{Im}(TS)\subset \text{Im}(S)\cap\text{Im}(T)$, hence $\dim(\text{Im}(S)\cap\text{Im}(T))\geq \dim(\text{Im}(ST))$.

It follows that
$$\dim(\text{Im}(S)) +\dim (\text{Im}(T))\geq \dim(\text{Im}(S+T))+\dim(\text{Im}(ST)),$$

or equivalently,
$$r(S)+r(T)\geq r(S+T)+r(ST).$$

Answer (score 0):

As we know, $Im\,(S+T)\subset Im\,S+Im\,T$, for this reason,

dim $Im\,(S+T)\le$dim$\,(ImS\,+\,ImT)=$dim$\,ImS\,$+dim$\,Im\,T$-dim$\,Im\,T\cap Im\,S$

Now, because the two operator commute, that is, $TS=ST$, we should have that $$Im\,ST\subseteq Im\,S\cap Im\,T$$
which implies

-dim$\,(Im\,S\cap Im\,T)$≤-dim$\,Im\,ST$
which proves the desired inequality.